# Promise falling on then , even with status 400

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm doing an upload check. As I understand it, the then method would only be executed if the promise was completed. However, in my code it executes the then method even with an error.

```
  const formdata = new FormData();
          formdata.append("file", image.file);
          api
            .post("/api/v1/file/upload", formdata)
            .then((response) => {
              const image = response.data.url
              api.put(`/api/v1/radio/${id}`, {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                image: image,
                }).then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
                }).catch(error => {
                  console.log(error);
                }) 
             }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error + 'upload file error')
             })
```

Comment: Status 400 means bad request, so there's something wrong with the way you are forming or sending the request. Check the values for the parameters and body of your requests and make sure it's what is expected

Comment: so the problem I'm having is that it landed on then even with this error, I force the error to happen and it landed on then, in the same way when success happens

Comment: Which request gives status 400? Post or Put? If it is put request, seems like post is successful, `.then` chain of post is being called, but then the put request fails and `.catch` of the put request catches this error.

Comment: the put request, when I force some error into it, instead of going to catch it goes to then